# Install Windows XP on a PC without a CD drive

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installation

My computer's CD burner is broken, but I have a different computer on LAN, running Windows 7, that has a working one. Is it possible to send the installation files over my LAN?  How would I do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: What kind of "installation file"? Are you just trying to install an *application or program* on the Windows XP machine, or are you trying to install *Windows **itself*** on it? It's pretty easy to transfer an ordinary file over the network assuming the two PCs are networked and booted, but installing an operating system over the network is more complicated.

Comment: Do you have a thumb drive? If so, you could use your Windows 7 computer to create a bootable Winodws XP installation on the thumb drive.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to install XP by running the disk in another computer, and sending the files to a different computer.(Short of using Windows Deployment, but thats another story). In your situation I would do one of two things:

1. Remove the working CD-ROM and install it in the other computer so it can read the XP install disk. This is your easiest/quickest solution. Swap it back when your done.
2. Create a bootable USB version of the Windows XP installation disk. http://www.techtipsgeek.com/install-windows-from-usb-flash-pen-drive/

Both methods will work, but swapping the CD-ROM will easily be the fastest way around this problem. By the time you get finished making a bootable USB drive, you could have swapped the CD-ROM and installed XP.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a bootable Windows 7 USB drive from your installation working copy, just folow this wiki it explains 4 ways to do that, i hope it will help ;) 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Bootable-Windows-7-or-Vista-USB-Drive

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a CD/DVD with a program's installation files, all you have to do is put that CD into the drive of the working computer, set up [File Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-essentials#1TC=windows-7) between the two computers, then copy and paste the CD's contents (all of the files) into a directory on the destination computer, then run it.