# Installing windowsXP or 7 from another partition, not a cd

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, installation, media

I have both a copy of windows XP and windows7 pro available. I want to install either on a computer (prefer XP)

But i don't have any CDROM drive at hand. I have another on another computer but it is too much work to remove it, add to the box, restore all back.

Is there any way to install windows XP, or failing that windows7pro, on that computer from another partition on the HD? or another sata HD?

i can use the other computer with linux to create a disk image and make it bootable somehow, if it is possible to run the windows installer then...

I can also use some "alternative" downloads if someone have a trustyworth image to point me to... i figure there is no harm on that since i have the valid licenses for this box. But obiously, I much preffer to use my trusty media. but in the end, computer will be a hometheater PC, so it wont have much senstitive data anyway, so i am up for it if it is the only option.

Comment: Does your machine have a floppy?  Can you boot into DOS?  If not, get a bootdisk from http://www.bootdisk.com/bootdisk.htm Once booted, run the the application winnt.exe from the i386 directory and it should install XP for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a virtual image of windows XP for free.
[Windows XP from MS and Virtual box](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-windows-xp-for-free-and-legally-straight-from-microsoft-si/)

Also, if you have the keys and media you could create an .iso or download the trial from MS and enter your key. Use a program like [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) to mount the .iso and have it treat the media like a cd-rom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. i will try to make that bootable somehow... i want to install on a real box, not a VM

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use a USB drive? if you have one just make it bootable check this : [Install Windows XP on a PC without a CD drive](https://superuser.com/questions/690789/install-windows-xp-on-a-pc-without-a-cd-drive/691184#691184)

Comment: in my memory i was sure windowxp installer didn't worked on purpose on USB media like SD cards and pen drives... i will try those. thanks